# Unable to access MySql db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been working on php for some time. I have cloned a git repo yesterday. Just after that i am able to connect to MySQL server, access MySQL db and phpmyadmin properly. Today, I started the server and tried to access phpmyadmin from xampp control panel, as soon as I try to open it, apache port is changing automatically to 49868 and mysql connection terminates.Then, again apache changes its ports to previous states.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

EDIT : I reinstalled everything and it worked.

Comment: care to explain negative votes?

Answer (score 0):

Check if another application is using port 80.

In command prompt use:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YNVR.png)

If windows verify if in task manager is already running XAMPP.

Comment: port 80 is free. Apache is using it.Nothing else.

Comment: as you try a reboot?

Comment: use button Netstat in xampp and post the print screen

Comment: In your browser if you use http:\\localhost:49888 is working?